# Replace negative values in a column as NaN in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have df as shown below.

```
Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-03             -23              
2020-02-06             14           
2020-02-09             23
2020-02-10             -2 
2020-02-11             23          
2020-02-13             NaN            
2020-02-20             29
```

From the above, I would like to replace negative values in a column `t_factor` as `NaN`

Expected output:

```
Date                t_factor     
2020-02-01             5             
2020-02-03             NaN              
2020-02-06             14           
2020-02-09             23
2020-02-10             NaN 
2020-02-11             23          
2020-02-13             NaN            
2020-02-20             29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['t_factor'] = df['t_factor'].mask(df['t_factor'].lt(0))
```

OR use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) and assign `np.nan`,

```
df.loc[df['t_factor'].lt(0), 't_factor'] = np.nan
```

Result:

```
         Date  t_factor
0  2020-02-01       5.0
1  2020-02-03       NaN
2  2020-02-06      14.0
3  2020-02-09      23.0
4  2020-02-10       NaN
5  2020-02-11      23.0
6  2020-02-13       NaN
7  2020-02-20      29.0
```

Comment: If I wants to replace with 0, How can I do?

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['t_factor'].lt(0), 't_factor'] = 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas `clip` implementation as well. This assigns values outside boundary to boundary values. And then chain this with a `replace` function as below:

```
df['t_factor'] = df['t_factor'].clip(-1).replace(-1, np.nan)
df
```

Output:

```
Date    t_factor
0   2020-02-01  5.0
1   2020-02-03  NaN
2   2020-02-06  14.0
3   2020-02-09  23.0
4   2020-02-10  NaN
5   2020-02-11  23.0
6   2020-02-13  NaN
7   2020-02-20  29.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) - by default it will replace values where the condition is False with `NaN`.

```
df["t_factor"] = df.t_factor.where(df.t_factor > 0)
```